# How to center a component in Material UI and make it responsive?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, mobile, material-ui, desktop

I don't quite understand the Material UI grid system. If I want to use a form component for login, what is the easiest way to center it on the screen on all devices (mobile and desktop)?

Answer (score 434, accepted):

Since you are going to use this on a login page.
Here is a code I used in a Login page using Material UI

**Material UI v5**

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={0}
  direction="column"
  alignItems="center"
  justifyContent="center"
  sx={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <LoginForm />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Material UI v4 and below**

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={0}
  direction="column"
  alignItems="center"
  justify="center"
  style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}
>
  <Grid item xs={3}>
    <LoginForm />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

this will make this login form at the center of the screen.

But still, IE doesn't support the Material-UI Grid and you will see some misplaced content in IE.

As pointed by @max, another option is,

```
<Grid container justifyContent="center">
  <Your centered component/>
</Grid>
```

*Please note that versions Material UI v4 and below should use justify="center" instead.*

However, using a Grid container without a Grid item is an undocumented behavior.

**Update on 2022-06-06**

In addition to that, another new and better approach will be using the `Box` component.

```
<Box
  display="flex"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
  minHeight="100vh"
>
  <YourComponent/>
</Box>
```

This was originally posted by Killian Huyghe as another answer.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: A little correction, for the Op's use case, the flex direction should be row>>>  direction="row"

Comment: Normally, alignItems=center and justify=center puts the component in the center of the page but it's not the case. Adding the style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }} does the job but it adds a scrolling bar in the page. How it will be fixed?

Comment: Thanks. After hours or searching, finally this is the one that helped me to achieve FormLabel and TextField side by side in the same row.

Comment: @Slim set CSS body margin:0

Comment: It's **justifyContent="center"** instead of **justify="center"** as of MUI v5

Comment: Gracias campeon...!

Comment: Grid is a bit overkill for centering items, I prefer the Box answers below

Comment: @ViktorMS sorry for the confusion. But Box wasn't even an option back in 2018, however, I admit that this should have been updated, so I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 85):

You can do this with the Box component:

```
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

...

<Box
  display="flex"
  justifyContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
  minHeight="100vh"
>
  <YourComponent/>
</Box>
```

Comment: this is my favorite answer, good technique

Comment: I was missing setting the minHeight

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, Grid is a bit overkill for OP's question

Comment: Would appreciate some explanations on why 4 attributes are required

Comment: @Julkar9 Box is just a wrapper over css, you need these 4 to: 1. use flex box, 2. center horizontally, 3. center vertically, 4. specify height so that vertical center works as expected

Answer (score 63):

Another option is:

```
<Grid container justify = "center">
  <Your centered component/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Although this works, using a Grid container without a Grid item is an undocumented behaviour and may break anytime (though it probably won't).

Comment: in mui v5 it would be justifyContent = "center"

Answer (score 21):

Here is another option without a grid:

```
<div
    style={{
        position: 'absolute', 
        left: '50%', 
        top: '50%',
        transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
    }}
>
    <YourComponent/>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked very well for me for centering a Material-UI <Fab> component.  As an add-on, in the translate method, the first parameter is the horizontal translation and the second is the vertical translation.

Comment: This solution has a problem, it will shorten the size of the component by 50% in width and height

Answer (score 14):

The @Nadun's version did not work for me, sizing wasn't working well. Removed the `direction="column"` or changing it to `row`, helps with building vertical login forms with responsive sizing.

```
<Grid
  container
  spacing={0}
  alignItems="center"
  justify="center"
  style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
>
  <Grid item xs={6}></Grid>
</Grid>;
```

Answer (score 14):

If you just need to center a couple of items in a row or column in **Material UI v5**, you can use [`Stack`](https://mui.com/components/stack/#main-content) instead of `Grid`:

```
<Stack alignItems="center">
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Item>Item 2</Item>
  <Item>Item 3</Item>
</Stack>
```

Another example with row direction:

```
<Stack direction="row" justifyContent="center">
  <Item>Item 1</Item>
  <Item>Item 2</Item>
  <Item>Item 3</Item>
</Stack>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Why use gap for the parent stack and spacing for the child stack.

Answer (score 6):

With other answers used, xs='auto' did a trick for me.

```
<Grid container
    alignItems='center'
    justify='center'
    style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>

    <Grid item xs='auto'>
        <GoogleLogin
            clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
            buttonText="Log in with Google"
            onSuccess={this.handleLogin}
            onFailure={this.handleLogin}
             cookiePolicy={'single_host_origin'}
         />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is wrap your content inside a Grid Container tag, specify the spacing, then wrap the actual content inside a Grid Item tag.

```
 <Grid container spacing={24}>
    <Grid item xs={8}>
      <leftHeaderContent/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid item xs={3}>
      <rightHeaderContent/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

Also, I've struggled with material grid a lot, I suggest you checkout flexbox which is built into CSS automatically and you don't need any addition packages to use. Its very easy to learn.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks, so I have use 3 Grid items and put the component in the middle to center it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make this component and use it everywhere you want. also you can add your props:

```
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

export default function Center(props: any) {

    const { children } = props

    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            {...props}
        >
            {children}
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little update 07-09-2021 'justify' is now 'justifyContent="center"'

https://material-ui.com/components/grid/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not answer OP's question

Answer (score 0):

The most versatile solution for me is using **container** and **item** props in combination.

The **container** and **item** props are two independent booleans; they can be combined to allow a Grid component to be both a flex container and child.

Grid MUI documentation - https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#responsive-values

```
<Grid container alignContent={'center'} xs={12}>
  <Grid container item xs={6} justifyContent={'start'}> 
    <span> content one </span> 
  </Grid>
  <Grid container item xs={6} justifyContent={'center'}> 
    <span> content two </span>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Image: [MUI Grid interactive demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Mri.png)

The interactive grid demo on the grid component page on MUI website (https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) is really easy to use for any configuration that one needs as it shows visually what it will do with what setting, basically a bunch of radio buttons to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Container](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-container/) component, which centers the content horizontally automatically.
Notice the [CssBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/) component which helps to kickstart an consistent, and simple baseline to build upon.

To determine the maxWidth of the container you can use one of the [Breakpoints](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/breakpoints/): `'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'`

```
import { Grid, Box, Container, CssBaseline } from '@mui/material';

const Foo = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Container maxWidth='sm'>
        <Grid item>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'green' }}>green</Box>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'grey' }}>grey</Box>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item>
          <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: 'orange' }}>orange</Box>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

export default Foo;
```

Answer (score -1):

<Box display={"inline-block"}> worked for me

Answer (score -2):

just do `style={{display:'flex';justifyContent:'center';alignItems:'center'}}`