# React - Material UI Items inside the grid refuse to center

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, containers, card

I want to center the cards inside the grid items, but it's not working.
As I understood from the documentations (https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) I should use justifyContent="center" at the  but that's not working, and in one of the answers on stack-overflow ([How to center a component in Material-UI and make it responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766693/how-to-center-a-component-in-material-ui-and-make-it-responsive)) someone used justify="center" instead, so I tried that too but it didn't work.

```
<Grid container justifyContent="center">
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4} >
    <Card style={{maxWidth: 345}}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          style={{height: 140}}
          image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom varient="h5" color="Secondary">
            100
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
    <Card style={{maxWidth: 345}}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          style={{height: 140}}
          image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom varient="h5" color="Secondary">
            100
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
    <Card style={{maxWidth: 345}}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          style={{height: 140}}
          image="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505740420928-5e560c06d30e?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8cHJvZHVjdHxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
          <Typography gutterBottom varient="h5" color="Secondary">
            100
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `xs` and `md` and change `justifyContent` to `space-around` to give proper spacing between them. Have a look at the code sandbox.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-tu-bdc3z?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I see, but still that doesn't explain why 'justifyContent' did not work, do you know why?